# in Jquery, how can I alert one part of a JSON object? I get "undefined"

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a an array:

```
$result = array('statusAlert' => 'Your input was validated'
                 'input' => $input); // $input is a string

json_encode($result);
```

in jQuery, I want to alert 'statusAlert' and 'input' separately? How do I access them?

I tried `alert(result.statusAlert)`, `alert(result[0])`, `alert(result.statusAlert[0])` but none of them has worked.

### Edit

I am trying to do that within the "success" callback function of `ajax()` in jQuery

When I alert(result), I get:

```
{"statusAlert":"Your input was validated","input":"this is the string input"}
```

Comment: Have you parsed the JSON? What do you get if you do `alert(typeof result);`?

Comment: Hi. I get "string". I will put the alert(result) in the original post. Thanks

Comment: Change your `.ajax()` request to include `dataType:'json'`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! Please copy paste it as an answer. I just have a question: The data i'm sending as POST is not in a JSON form. Only what comes back from PHP is. Isn't that "dataType" supposed to *restrict* the kind of data that is *sent* or *received*? Or does it expand the range of data types? Thanks a lot

Comment: received.  rtm - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @alexx0186: No, it just relates to the anticipated response. Not the posted data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `.ajax()` request to include `dataType:'json'`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you specify `dataType: 'json'` in your `$.ajax` parameters?

Presuming you have and you've used the jQuery `$.getJSON` or `$.ajax` functions and it's still not working, then your result should be an array, not an object, as you created it in PHP as an array. You'll be looking to read it as:

```
alert(result['statusAlert']);
```

and

```
alert(result['input']);
```

Comment: Hi, it was indeed the dataType that solved my problem. I also tried alert(result['statusAlert']) but I get undefined. I'll stick your first solution. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

If you have a valid json like this

```
'{"statusAlert":"Your input was validated","input":"this is the string input"}'
```

You can get the values like this

```
jsonObj.statusAlert

jsonObj.input
```

Here is the sample http://jsfiddle.net/kfrTz/8/

You can use http://jsonlint.com/ to verify your jSon is in correct form or not.

Specifying `json` as the data type value in your ajax request will make sure the reponse is coming back as `json` format to the success callback.

```
$.ajax({
   url:"yourserverpage.php",
   datatype='json',
   success: function(data) {
      alert(data.statusAlert);
   }

 });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your response. I used the dataType: 'json'. it seems that it's equivalent to the JSON.parse. Thanks for the tip!